# label and change colors to bar charts using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to replicate the bar charts as the figure 1. in this paper (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10461-020-02820-6.pdf)
and my data look like

```
dat <- read.table(text = "    item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4 item_5

StronglyAgree   40  30 20 10 45
Agree   30  30 45 30 5
Netural   20  20 5 10 25
Disagree   5  10 8  25 15
StronglyDisagree   5  10 15 25 10",sep = "",header = TRUE)
```

and I have tried the code, which did not quite give me exactly the figure I want

```
datm <- dat %>% 
  mutate(ind = factor(row_number())) %>%  
  gather(variable, value, -ind)

ggplot(datm, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = ind)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+
  coord_flip()
```

I would like to:

1. if possible, change the name 'item 1,item2...' to exactly the question
2. recode the colors, ideally change 'strongly disagree & disagree' to the red theme, neutral  to grey, and agree & strongly agree to the green theme
3. add the legend

thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

you can manipulate the colors and texts in this template ;

```
ggplot(datm, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = ind)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+
    scale_x_discrete(labels=c('item_5'='You','item_4'='Can','item_3'='Type','item_2'='Whatever','item_1'='You Want'))+
    scale_fill_manual(breaks = waiver(),
                      values = c('red','yellow','grey','lightgreen','green'),
                      labels = c('strongly disagree','disagree','neutral','agree','strongly agree'))+
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! very helpful! a follow-up question. How can I keep the order of the items in axis? like I want to list them 1-5 from the top to the bottom

Comment: you are welcome, consider approving if you find satisfying enough.

Comment: @Dr.KnowNothing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph

Comment: I do not think this link provides the answer...also it's so weird why 'strongly disagree and disagree' were on the right of each bar... is there a way that I can start the bar from strongly disagree to neutral to strongly agree?